# "Unable to find explicit activity class" using an explicit intent in Android application

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am very new to creating apps and I simply want another activity to show once a button is pressed. I've done this with other projects without a problem and for 3 days now I cannot seem to understand why my button isn't working. I get the "Unfortunately, TurtleMath has stopped." TurtleMath is the name of the app. I think it is a really dumb mistake or syntax error I made but I can't seem to find it. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you. I posted the PCalculator.java  along with PythagoreanCalculator.java. The buttons are hypotenuse and side and I want them to open PythagoreanCalculator.java. If XML file are needed please let me know and I'll add them in.

```
public class PCalulator extends Activity {

private Button mSideButton;
private Button mHypotenuseButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pcalulator);

    mSideButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.side_button);
    mSideButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent i = new Intent(PCalulator.this, PythagoreanCalculator.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    mHypotenuseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hypotenuse_button);
    mHypotenuseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
             Intent i = new Intent(PCalulator.this, PythagoreanCalculator.class);
             startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pcalulator, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

---

```
public class PythagoreanCalculator extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_pythagorean_calculator);
}
}
```

---

```
    04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272): Process: com.esol.turtlemath, PID: 27272
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.esol.turtlemath/com.esol.turtlemath.PythagoreanCalculator}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3468)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3429)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3671)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3639)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at com.esol.turtlemath.PCalulator$2.onClick(PCalulator.java:38)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4442)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18473)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
04-11 12:14:45.950: E/AndroidRuntime(27272):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your error log please.

Comment: I just posted it thanks for your help

Comment: @user3524448 post you manifest.\

Comment: Agreed with @Hariharan, post your androidmanifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks fine. Is the other activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

**EDIT** Your problem is definitely that the class wasn't declared in the manifest by looking at your error log. Declare it and you should be fine.

Comment: No, it isn't but that has not been a problem before with other applications. Should it be in it though?

Comment: @user3524448 As long as your second activity is idle it won't show any error. But When it will come to picture then it will show you error if  not declared in your manifest.xml

Comment: All activities should be declared in the android manifest. That is how they are registered by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Add below line in your manifest before `</application>`

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.esol.turtlemath.PythagoreanCalculator" />
```